# Como deixar uma div 'fixed' limitada por uma div principal?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou tentando fazer algo parecido a isto: https://www.chipart.com.br/computadores/monte_seu_pc
onde a div contendo os valores da compra fica fixa somente enquanto as opções de customização estão visíveis, porém creio que não seja possível fazer isto com 'fixed', a única coisa que consegui fazer até o momento é deixar esta 'caixa' com os valores fixa em toda a página.

Alguém saberia me indicar alguma solução?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nisto... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o plugin jquery [Sticky-Kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/).

> Sticky-kit fixa os elementos na página quando o usuário faz scroll de maneira que esse elemento fica sempre visível.
>
> [image]

Com ele basta selecionar um elemento e aplicar uma função:

```
$("#sidebar").stick_in_parent();
```

---

Exemplo prático:

http://jsfiddle.net/jomar/w4Lu98nd/1/

Comment: Desculpa @mdma, eu queria responder sugerindo o mesmo `plugin`, mas para não "duplicar" acresci apenas um exemplo da utilização no `fiddle`. :D

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usando jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > POSIÇÃO_Y) {
         $('.sua_div').addClass('fixed');
     }
     else {
         $('.sua_div').removeClass('fixed');
     }
});
```

Assim, sempre que o scroll da página passar do `POSIÇÃO_Y`, a div terá a classe `.fixed`, aí no CSS você declara essa classe pra div ficar com `position: fixed`

Answer (score -1):

Basta criar uma `div` fixada que aparece e desaparece utilizando o `display:none`. Isso acontece também em [pc gamer](https://pcgamer.page).

Comment: Tem como aprofundar sua resposta? Dá para fazer um exemplo executável usando os snippets aqui do Stack Overfllow